# Failed to get characters/triangles

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I wanted to read characters/triangles from a bar.

Firstly I applied Otsu with different values to this bar but couldn't get the all characters properly. Also I tried triangle detection but couldn't extract again. The characters' colours are varying. Could someone give another way/algorithm to extract them? Also, is there any way to color sweeping, I mean try all colours then if exist, extract (extract all colored from black&white backgrounded image) ?

```
ret,im1 = cv2.threshold(crop_img,0,255,cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

The challenges, the last one is the hardest

[image]

The best one I got which is unsuccesful:

[image]

Comment: Did you try converting to HSV or a similar color space that has saturation or chromacity as a channel? If your background is always black and white, then you should be able to easily pick up pixels that have color with a single threshold on that channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is best solved using color separation. You can use the `inrange()` function for that ([docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.5/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga48af0ab51e36436c5d04340e036ce981)). This is usually done best in the HSV colorspace. The code below shows how you can do this.

You can use [this script](https://github.com/twenty-twenty/opencv_basic_color_separator) to find the value ranges you need to do color separation. It also has a sample image that can help you understand how HSV works.

Result:
[image]

Purple only:
[image]

Code:

```
    import numpy as np 
    import cv2
    # load image
    img = cv2.imread("image.png")

     # Convert BGR to HSV
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    # define range of HSV-color
    lower_val = np.array([0,50,80])
    upper_val = np.array([179,255,255])
    # purple only
    #lower_val = np.array([140,50,80])
    #upper_val = np.array([170,255,255])

    # Threshold the HSV image to get a mask that holds the markings
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_val, upper_val)

    # create an image of the markings with background excluded
    img_masked = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img,mask=mask)

    # display image
    cv2.imshow("result", img_masked)

    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```